# Make a new partition in root directory '/'

Tags: root, partitioning

I have the 'rootfs' filesystem mounted on '/'. How can i partition '/' into 2 partitions such that rootfs is mounted on the first partition and another directory say 'temp' is mounted on the second partition. Kindly give me directions and tutorials which will help me accomplish this. I am very new to this. So kindly let me know the basic things to know solve this problem.

Kindly note that my '/' partition is on RAM and not on harddisk

Answer (score 0):

You should learn how to use fdisk, /etc/fstab and mount.

I can recommand you to read this disk partionning guide : http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/fdisk_partitioning.html

Comment: Hi Sébastien, Thanks for the quick response and partitioning guide. I forgot to mention that my '/' partition is on RAM and not on harddisk. Kindly direct me again

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you with RAM :( Perhaps you can add more details/tags on your Question to get help. Are you trying to build a LiveCD ?